# Навигация по форме с помощью клавиатуры

Tags: администрирование, браузер, клавиатура, плагин, opera

Как в браузере выбирать элементы формы (логина, например) с помощью клавиатуры? Я могу перечислять все возможные элементы с помощью последовательного нажатия Tab, однако это неудобно из-за множества лишних элементов. Как ограничить их только предлагаемой на странице формой или, если можно, как перейти к конкретному полю с помощью клавиатуры?

Answer (score 0):

воспользуйтесь атрибутом tabindex, с помощью которого сделаете нужную вам последовательность фокуса